# Using edge-loops/knife tools on character model?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, knife-tool

I am doing an example model through a workbook, and I am stuck at a specific section. This section is asking me to add edge-loops to my model (creature figure). I can not get the edge loops to work correctly and it is giving me a hard time. It also mentions using the knife tool to make cuts through the model down the center if the topology creates an issue in getting a clean cut, which mine seems to be doing. So I try and still I get the same results. I am in edit mode with wire-frame view active, but all I get is a purple dot at the midpoints between the points created by my skin modifier (the book does not mention doing anything such as pushing the "X" to close it or applying the modifier, so I have not) that does nothing related to the desired results. I want a complete cut so I can mirror the model without having to mirror the left half of the model into the right side. Any help is appreciated. (Also, sorry for the long question. Tried to be as specific as I could be.) I will also try to add pictures and the model's file for you to experiment with.[image: trying to cut along highlighted area][image: example photo of the purple dot from ctrl + r]

Comment: I only own that version of the 3D model. I do not own the concept or the name. As I stated, this idea came from a workbook titled "3D Blender Cookbook" and any names or ideas come from that workbook. In the model listed, there are background images, which also belong to the workbook.

Comment: Also, if anyone wants the .blend file, I do not know at the moment how to offer that. If you would not mind telling me, I could get it to you.

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share your blend file.